# How to make Regexp condition statement into false

Tags: javascript

How to make regexp condition into false without using else statement

```
if (emailReg.test(emailValue)) {

}
```

Comment: `if (!emailReg.test(emailValue))` ?

Comment: With the logical NOT operator `!`. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just negate it:

```
if(!emailReg.test(emailValue)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!true; // Returns false.
!false; // Returns true
```

given the if case,

`emailReg.test(emailValue)`, if this is true you can flip it with 'logical not' operator from javaScript.

`emailReg.test(emailValue) === true` and `!emailReg.test(emailValue) === false`

### so answer you are looking for would look like following.

```
if (!emailReg.test(emailValue)) {

}
```

---